# Separable Normed Vector Space can be written as the closure of a countable union of subspaces.

Tags: normed-spaces

I'm trying to follow the proof of the following theorem. It seems simple enough but I'm stuck on the last inclusion. I think I'm getting thrown by the closure operator.

**Theorem:** Let $X$ denote a separable normed vector space. Then there exists a countably infinite family $(X_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of finite dimensional subspaces of $X$ such that
\begin{equation}
\text{dim}\;X_n = n, \;\; X_n\subset X_{n+1}, \;\; n\geq1 \;\; \text{and} \;\; \overline{\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n}
\end{equation}

The sketch of the proof is as follows. Find $x_k \in X,\; k\geq 1$ such that
\begin{equation}
\overline{\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \{x_k\}} = X
\end{equation}
Which we can do by the assumption that $X$ is separable. Then we find vectors $e_k \in X$ recursively by

\begin{equation}
e_1 = x_{\sigma(1)} \;\;\; \text{with} \; \sigma(1)=1 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
e_k = e_{\sigma(k)} \;\;\; \text{with} \; \sigma(k)=\min\{m\geq \sigma(k-1)+1;\; x_m \notin \text{Span}(e_l)_{l=1}^{k-1}\}\;\;k \geq 2
\end{equation}

Then the subspaces defined by $X_n =\text{Span}(e_k)_{k=1}^n$ satisfy the properties required.

Also since
\begin{equation}
\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \{x_k\} \subset \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n
\end{equation}

we have

\begin{equation}
X = \overline{\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \{x_k\}} \subset \overline{\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n}
\end{equation}

but I'm slightly unsure of the reverse inclusion, $X \supset \overline{\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n}$
It wuld be great if someone could point out what silly mistake I'm making.

Comment: $X$ is your universal space and all sets you are considering are subsets of $X$ So there is nothing left to prove.